# Laurent series $\frac{e^z}{z^2 -1}$ about $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Where to start? I know I need to make all the z's into $ z-1 $'s, so $ e\cdot e^{z-1} $ and denominator into $ (z-1)(z+1) $, but from there what do I do with the denominator?

Comment: I'd write $z=w+1$ and so find the Laurent series of $e^{w+1}/((w+1)^2-1)$ at $w=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I just read this http://sym.lboro.ac.uk/resources/Handout-Laurent.pdf and everything makes sense now. My textbook is very shallow and goes over this topic very quick.